# Pythonで2次元リストの条件に合うインデックスを抽出

Tags: python

2つ以上の特定の要素を含むリストのインデックスを抽出したいです。

具体的には

```
li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

から2と3を含むリストのインデックス抽出し

```
list = [0,1,4,5,6]
```

となるlistの作成をしたいと考えています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 何か調べられたり、試したコードがあれば掲載してください。

Answer (score 1):

リスト内包表記と[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)、[set型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)を組み合わせれば一行で抽出できます。

```
li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
list = [i for i, l in enumerate(li) if set([2, 3]).issubset(l)]
list
# [0, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のコードで出来ます。

```
    li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

    newList=[]
    
    for index,innerList in enumerate(li):
        if 2 in innerList and 3 in innerList:
            newList.append(index)
            
    print(newList)
    #出力結果 [0, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

まず、新しいindexを含む空のリスト`newList=[]`を作成します。
enumerate(li)で、リスト内のリスト(innerList )とindex番号を抽出してfor文を回します。

リスト内に2が含まれているかどうかを `if 2 in innerList` で調べて、リスト内に3が含まれているかどうかを`3 in innerList` で調べます。

もし、両方含まれていたら、index番号をnewListに追加します。

Answer (score 0):

numpy を使って変数 `li` を `numpy.ndarray` 型にすると少し簡単になります。

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> li = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6],
  [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]
])
>>> np.intersect1d(*[np.where(li==k)[0] for k in (2, 3)])
array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPyのブール演算を使った方法です。探す値が何個であっても可能です。

```
import numpy as np

def search_index(li, values):
    arr = np.asarray(li)
    arr_v = np.asarray(values).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
    return (arr == arr_v).any(2).all(0).nonzero()[0]
```

動作例：

```
In [11]: li = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

In [12]: search_index(li, [2, 3])
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64)

In [13]: search_index(li, [2, 3, 4])
Out[13]: array([1, 4, 6], dtype=int64)

In [14]: search_index(li, [1])
Out[14]: array([0, 5], dtype=int64)
```